# Suggestions of books or sites that review growing networks?

Tags: networking

A few years ago our network infrastructure was quite simple with just 3 switches, a single subnet, no VLANs, etc.

Fast forward to today and we have over a dozen switches, an iSCSI SAN with 3 arrays and multipathing, VMware infrastructure, VoIP, perimiter networks, and more.

Some questions that have arisen:

- Do we have too many vLANs? Too many subnets? When to subnet? When to VLAN?
- Should we define vLANs on every switch, or just on the core switch, or ???
- Should we consider adding an administrative vLAN? Pros/Cons?
- What traffic should we filter through the firewall, and what should we handle through VLAN ACLs?
- How do we name the networks? Physical and logical? eg. we have our "LAN" and a "DMZ" and a network that sits between them with no name.

We are planning on both training and getting outside help in the coming years, but I'd love to educate myself a little more now and simple google searches aren't helping me out much for the above questions.

Answer (score 4):

["The Practice of System and Network Administration" by Tom Limoncelli, et al.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321492668) is widely considered to be the bible of this field.